# How to config nltk data directory from code?

Tags: python, path, directory, nlp, nltk

How to config nltk data directory from code?

Comment: Related: [Change nltk.download() path directory from default ~/ntlk_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857382/change-nltk-download-path-directory-from-default-ntlk-data)

Answer (score 84):

Just change items of `nltk.data.path`, it's a simple list.

Comment: or set NLTK_DATA environment variable.

Comment: My nltk.data.path has `'/home/aankney/nltk_data'` as the first element of the list BUT I'm on a server and want `nltk_data` to be shared by other people using the server. How do I prevent nltk from using this as one of the download paths?

Answer (score 54):

From the code, http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/data.html:

> ```
> ``nltk:path``: Specifies the file stored in the NLTK data
>  package at *path*.  NLTK will search for these files in the
>  directories specified by ``nltk.data.path``.
> ```

Then within the code:

```
######################################################################
# Search Path
######################################################################

path = []
"""A list of directories where the NLTK data package might reside.
   These directories will be checked in order when looking for a
   resource in the data package.  Note that this allows users to
   substitute in their own versions of resources, if they have them
   (e.g., in their home directory under ~/nltk_data)."""

# User-specified locations:
path += [d for d in os.environ.get('NLTK_DATA', str('')).split(os.pathsep) if d]
if os.path.expanduser('~/') != '~/':
    path.append(os.path.expanduser(str('~/nltk_data')))

if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    # Common locations on Windows:
    path += [
        str(r'C:\nltk_data'), str(r'D:\nltk_data'), str(r'E:\nltk_data'),
        os.path.join(sys.prefix, str('nltk_data')),
        os.path.join(sys.prefix, str('lib'), str('nltk_data')),
        os.path.join(os.environ.get(str('APPDATA'), str('C:\\')), str('nltk_data'))
    ]
else:
    # Common locations on UNIX & OS X:
    path += [
        str('/usr/share/nltk_data'),
        str('/usr/local/share/nltk_data'),
        str('/usr/lib/nltk_data'),
        str('/usr/local/lib/nltk_data')
    ]
```

To modify the path, simply append to the list of possible paths:

```
import nltk
nltk.data.path.append("/home/yourusername/whateverpath/")
```

Or in windows:

```
import nltk
nltk.data.path.append("C:\somewhere\farfar\away\path")
```

Comment: What directory would contain this file?

Comment: it's in the original source code of NLTK. Go to the directory where you save the source code then go to `nltk/nltk/data`

Comment: take a look at `magically_find_nltk_data()` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382937/nltk-doesnt-add-nltk-data-to-search-path/36383314#36383314

Answer (score 32):

I use append, example

```
nltk.data.path.append('/libs/nltk_data/')
```

Answer (score 22):

Instead of adding `nltk.data.path.append('your/path/to/nltk_data')` to every script, NLTK accepts NLTK_DATA environment variable. ([code link](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py#L88))

Open `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.profile`) with text editor (e.g. `nano`, `vim`, `gedit`), and add following line:

```
export NLTK_DATA="your/path/to/nltk_data"
```

Execute `source` to load environmental variable

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

#### Test

Open python and execute following lines

```
import nltk
nltk.data.path
```

Your can see your nltk data path already in there.

Reference: @alvations's answer on
[nltk/nltk #1997](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1997#issuecomment-377885461)

Answer (score 2):

Using fnjn's advice above on printing out the path:

```
print(nltk.data.path)
```

I saw the path strings in this type of format on windows:

```
C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\AppData\\Roaming\\SPB_Data
```

So I switched my path from the python type forward slash '/', to a double backslash '\\' when I used path.append:

```
nltk.data.path.append("C:\\workspace\\my_project\\data\\nltk_books")
```

The exception went away.

Answer (score 1):

For those using uwsgi:

I was having trouble because I wanted a uwsgi app (running as a different user than myself) to have access to nltk data that I had previously downloaded. What worked for me was adding the following line to `myapp_uwsgi.ini`:

```
env = NLTK_DATA=/home/myuser/nltk_data/
```

This sets the environment variable `NLTK_DATA`, as suggested by @schemacs.
You may need to restart your uwsgi process after making this change.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to get ahead of it.

try 
    import nltk 
    nltk.download()

When the window box pops up asking if you want to download the corpus , you can specify there which directory it is to be downloaded to.