# How do I download NLTK data?

Tags: python, nltk

Updated answer:NLTK works for 2.7 well. I had 3.2. I uninstalled 3.2 and installed 2.7. Now it works!!

I have installed NLTK and tried to download NLTK Data. What I did was to follow the instrution on this site: http://www.nltk.org/data.html

I downloaded NLTK, installed it, and then tried to run the following code:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

It gave me the error message like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    nltk.download()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'download'
 Directory of C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages
```

Tried both `nltk.download()` and `nltk.downloader()`, both gave me error messages.

Then I used `help(nltk)` to pull out the package, it shows the following info:

```
NAME
    nltk

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    align
    app (package)
    book
    ccg (package)
    chat (package)
    chunk (package)
    classify (package)
    cluster (package)
    collocations
    corpus (package)
    data
    decorators
    downloader
    draw (package)
    examples (package)
    featstruct
    grammar
    help
    inference (package)
    internals
    lazyimport
    metrics (package)
    misc (package)
    model (package)
    parse (package)
    probability
    sem (package)
    sourcedstring
    stem (package)
    tag (package)
    test (package)
    text
    tokenize (package)
    toolbox
    tree
    treetransforms
    util
    yamltags

FILE
    c:\python32\lib\site-packages\nltk
```

I do see Downloader there, not sure why it does not work. Python 3.2.2, system Windows vista.

Comment: Short note: I do not know what the problem is, but what you are doing is correct and should give you a GUI to choose what to download (i.e. you're not doing it wrong, but something *is* wrong)

Comment: From where did you install NLTK? I highly suggest you install it through a package manager like [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to handle all the dependencies for you.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. Do you mean I should install pip first and then use it to install NLTK?

Comment: Correct that is what @MichaelAquilina means.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. Do you mean I should install pip first and then use it to install NLTK? I found this resource: [link](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#id5) Should I just copy paste the content in `get-pip.py` link to a python file, save it to `c:/python32`? I would really appreciate more information on the details. Thanks.

Comment: Just follow the commands on the [website](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) to install pip (you will need to use the command-prompt window to do so). Once its installed, use a command-prompt window and type "pip install nltk". Once that's done try running the nltk command again to see if you pip resolved your issue.

Comment: So I am not seeing anything to download except that huge blob. It did not see if I should copy paste that text or do something else before I run the below it, or should I copy paste the whole thing and save it somewhere?

Comment: installation from terminal `python3 -m nltk.downloader all`

Answer (score 102):

## TL;DR

To download a particular dataset/models, use the `nltk.download()` function, e.g. if you are looking to download the `punkt` sentence tokenizer, use:

```
$ python3
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

If you're unsure of which data/model you need, you can start out with the basic list of data + models with:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular')
```

It will download a list of "popular" resources, these includes:

```
<collection id="popular" name="Popular packages">
      <item ref="cmudict" />
      <item ref="gazetteers" />
      <item ref="genesis" />
      <item ref="gutenberg" />
      <item ref="inaugural" />
      <item ref="movie_reviews" />
      <item ref="names" />
      <item ref="shakespeare" />
      <item ref="stopwords" />
      <item ref="treebank" />
      <item ref="twitter_samples" />
      <item ref="omw" />
      <item ref="wordnet" />
      <item ref="wordnet_ic" />
      <item ref="words" />
      <item ref="maxent_ne_chunker" />
      <item ref="punkt" />
      <item ref="snowball_data" />
      <item ref="averaged_perceptron_tagger" />
    </collection>
```

---

## EDITED

In case anyone is avoiding errors from downloading larger datasets from `nltk`, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135306/610569

```
$ rm /Users/<your_username>/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_lite.zip
$ rm -r /Users/<your_username>/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_lite
$ python

>>> import nltk
>>> dler = nltk.downloader.Downloader()
>>> dler._update_index()
>>> dler._status_cache['panlex_lite'] = 'installed' # Trick the index to treat panlex_lite as it's already installed.
>>> dler.download('popular')
```

## Updated

[From v3.2.5, NLTK has a more informative error message](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1806) when `nltk_data` resource is not found, e.g.:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/l/alvas/git/nltk/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 128, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "/Users//alvas/git/nltk/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 94, in sent_tokenize
    tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
  File "/Users/alvas/git/nltk/nltk/data.py", line 820, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "/Users/alvas/git/nltk/nltk/data.py", line 938, in _open
    return find(path_, path + ['']).open()
  File "/Users/alvas/git/nltk/nltk/data.py", line 659, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')

  Searched in:
    - '/Users/alvas/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

## Related

- To **find `nltk_data` directory** (auto-magically), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36383314/610569
- To **download `nltk_data` to a different path**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48634212/610569
- To **config `nltk_data` path** (i.e. set a different path for NLTK to find `nltk_data`), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987374/610569

Comment: To install nltk_data in a conda environment, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53464117/501086

Answer (score 36):

Try

`nltk.download('all')`

this will download all the data and no need to download individually.

Comment: in my case it was not loading UI.. do not know why... but this helped me. thanks.

Comment: FYI - as of 2019/12/15, that whole folder is about 3.2 GB, including the zip files.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FlorinAndrei for that info.

Answer (score 17):

Install Pip: run in terminal : `sudo easy_install pip`

Install Numpy (optional): run : `sudo pip install -U numpy`

Install NLTK: run : `sudo pip install -U nltk`

Test installation: run:  `python`

then type : `import nltk`

To download the corpus

run : `python -m nltk.downloader all`

Answer (score 13):

Do not name your file nltk.py I used the same code and name it nltk, and got the same error as you have, I changed the file name and it went well.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://user:password@proxy.example.com:8080')
nltk.download()
```

Answer (score 10):

Please Try

```
import nltk

nltk.download()
```

After running this you get something like this

```
NLTK Downloader
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then, `Press d`

Do As Follows:

```
Downloader> d all
```

You will get following message on completion, and Prompt then `Press q`
Done downloading collection all

Answer (score 5):

you can't have a saved python file called `nltk.py` because the interpreter is reading from that and not from the actual file.

Change the name of your file that the python shell is reading from and try what you were doing originally:

`import nltk` and then `nltk.download()`

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple....

1. Open pyScripter or any editor
2. Create a python file eg: install.py
3. write the below code in it.

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

4. A pop-up window will apper and click on download .

[image: The download window]]

Comment: The pop up window is not opening . I have tried many times . The version of the nltk is also new one which is 3.4.1 . Now tell what should be issue ?

Comment: @HamzaTahir Same happened with me, I restarted my kernel

Answer (score 4):

If you are running a really old version of nltk, then there is indeed no download module available ([reference](https://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=303))

Try this:

```
import nltk
print(nltk.__version__)
```

As per the reference, anything after 0.9.5 should be fine

Comment: This is actually what I suspected, which is why I suggested the OP uses pip to install NLTK instead.

Comment: It won't even print out the version info. The version is 2.0.4. That is the link I followed from the book **Natural Language Processing with Python**. Here is the [link]http://www.nltk.org/install.html.

Comment: Ok, that's the latest. I guess this isn't it then. Let's leave it here for future reference

Comment: Does any of nltk work for you? try running: `nltk.word_tokenize("hello world")` and see if gives you any output

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue. Probably check if you are using proxy.

If yes, set up the proxy before doing download:

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
```

Answer (score 2):

you should add python to your PATH during installation of python...after installation.. open cmd prompt type  command-`pip   install nltk`
then go to IDLE and open a new file..save it as file.py..then open file.py
type the following:
import nltk

```
nltk.download()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try download the zip files from http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ and then unzip, save in your Python folder, such as  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\nltk_data

Comment: This is the method I had to use (in modified form) for a Linux server that is not connected to the internet.  I unzipped it under a directory I created, /usr/share/nltk_data/tokenizers/

Answer (score 1):

if you have already saved a file name nltk.py and again rename as my_nltk_script.py. check whether you have still the file nltk.py existing. If yes, then delete them and run the file my_nltk.scripts.py it should work!

Answer (score 0):

just do like

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

then you will be show a popup asking what to download , select 'all'. it will take some time because of its size, but eventually we will get it.

and if you are using Google Colab, you can use

```
nltk.download(download_dir='/content/nltkdata')
```

after running that you will be asked to select from a list

```
NLTK Downloader
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------
d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) 
Quit
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------
Downloader> d
```

here you have to enter d as you want to download.
after that you will be asked to enter the identifier that you want to download . You can see the list of available indentifier with l command or if you want all of them just enter 'all' in the input box.
then you will see something like -

```
Downloading collection 'all'
       | 
       | Downloading package abc to /content/nltkdata...
       |   Unzipping corpora/abc.zip.
       | Downloading package alpino to /content/nltkdata...
       |   Unzipping corpora/alpino.zip.
       | Downloading package biocreative_ppi to /content/nltkdata...
       |   Unzipping corpora/biocreative_ppi.zip.
       | Downloading package brown to /content/nltkdata...
       |   Unzipping corpora/brown.zip.
       | Downloading package brown_tei to /content/nltkdata...
       |   Unzipping corpora/brown_tei.zip.
       | Downloading package cess_cat to /content/nltkdata...
       |   Unzipping corpora/cess_cat.zip.
.
.
. 
 |   Unzipping models/wmt15_eval.zip.
       | Downloading package mwa_ppdb to /content/nltkdata...
       |   Unzipping misc/mwa_ppdb.zip.
       | 
     Done downloading collection all

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloader> q
True
```

at last you can enter q to quit.

Answer (score -4):

You may try:

```
>> $ import nltk
>> $ nltk.download_shell()
>> $ d
>> $ *name of the package*
```

happy nlp'ing.