# Unable to download files from NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to run the below code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

I get the NLTK downloader where I select Corpora tab and try to download wordnet (or any other file) I am getting the below error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 495, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 1914, in _monitor_message_queue
    self._select(msg.package.id)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'id'

Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)
```

and

```
<urlopen error [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I believe it's a network issue, how can I resolve it? (Just an FYI, I can connect to the internet and browse normally)

Comment: Can you figure out which host it fails to resolve?  What version of NLTK?

Comment: Tangentially, can you check that it's not one of the issues on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data

Comment: @tripleee: Not sure which host failed to resolve... My version of NLTK is 3.0.5... I have checked the post but no luck

Comment: I'm not too sure it's a network issue. Try using the downloader non-interactively, e.g. `nltk.download("brown")`; if the problem remains, at least you know it's not in the tk window handler. If you have python 3 on your computer, try the download there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you avoid Tkinter. You can install corpora from the command line like this `sudo python nltk.downloader wordnet`. To download all corpora required for using the book, do `python nltk.downloader book`.