# How to download all packages in nltk in python

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

While downloading NLTK packages in python the package named PANLEX_LITE ia downloading upto 60% and showing status download completed but when I tried to open it it showing an error message please help me out on how to download it and what happens if I proceed without downloading it???

Comment: What is the error message, you see?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is showing WinRaR diagnostic messages as damaged or unknown format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download NLTK data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data)

Comment: I like this answer actually http://stackoverflow.com/a/38135306/2178980

Answer (score 5):

Use the `halt_on_error` parameter to skip errors.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular', halt_on_error=False)
```

If you're not going to use the `panlex` corpus, then not downloading it will not affect the rest of the modules in `nltk`.

You're encouraged to report the problem on the download of the panlex corpus to https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/983

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there a way I can download all except panlex corpus? The entire downloading process is hanging due to panlex.