# NLTK panlex_lite giving me error

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to use NLTK for my NLP learning in Python.

Certain package called "panlex_lite" keeps giving me error so I tried using the following:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('all', halt_on_error = False)
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package panlex_lite to
[nltk_data]    |     /Users/Harshil/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/panlex_lite.zip.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
  nltk.download('all', halt_on_error = False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 664, in download
for msg in self.incr_download(info_or_id, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 543, in incr_download
for msg in self.incr_download(info.children, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 529, in incr_download
for msg in self._download_list(info_or_id, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 572, in _download_list
for msg in self.incr_download(item, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 549, in incr_download
for msg in self._download_package(info, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 638, in _download_package
for msg in _unzip_iter(filepath, zipdir, verbose=False):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 2039, in _unzip_iter
outfile.write(contents)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Anyway to fix this? I've tried using "halt_on_error = False" method but it still gives me error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a "dirty" hack:

```
$ rm /Users/Harshil/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_lite.zip
$ rm -r /Users/Harshil/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_lite
$ python

>>> import nltk
>>> dler = nltk.downloader.Downloader()
>>> dler._update_index()
>>> dler._status_cache['panlex_lite'] = 'installed' # Trick the index to treat panlex_lite as it's already installed.
>>> dler.download('all')
```

---

Also, try `earthy`:

```
pip install earthy
```

**TL;DR**:

```
import earthy
path_to_nltk_data = '/home/yourusername/nltk_data/'
earthy.download('all', path_to_nltk_data) # Excludes the third party (non-NLTK) packages.
```

To download `panlex_lite` exclusively:

```
import earthy
earthy.download('panlex_lite', path_to_nltk_data)
```

To download all third-party datasets not natively hosted on `nltk_data` github:

```
import earthy
earthy.download('third_party', path_to_nltk_data')
```