# PermissionError when downloading NLTK data

Tags: python, shell, anaconda, nltk

I use Anaconda's Python 3.6.3 distribution and it comes with NLTK installed, but not with NLTK DATA, which I need for a project, the problem is, when I try to install with

```
nltk.download()
```

I get

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/nltk_data'
```

So, I did some research, and I see people suggesting to run Python as

```
sudo python
```

but if I do that, it will launch the base Linux's Python, not Anaconda's.

**tl;dr**

I need some way to do something like

```
sudo conda python
```

If you have other suggestions that might work, I'll take it too.

Thanks!

Comment: Which OS are you using, Mac or Linux? Which setup are you in? Did you create an awesome/gcp instance? Use someone else's instance? Or did you install an os fresh from your machine? Or are you using a school computer with your account? Which directory so you have access to to save your files? Have you tried

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, it's freshly installed in a new, personal machine, I have complete access/control over everything

Answer (score 4):

Find out which directory you can write files to. E.g. if it's `/home/alvas/testdir`

Then

```
>>> pip install -U nltk
>>> mkdir -p /home/alvas/testdir 
>>> python -m nltk.download popular -d /home/alvas/testdir
```

If you want to know how to configure the custom path for `nltk_data`, at the start of your Python code:

```
import nltk
nltk.data.path.append('/home/alvas/testdir')
```

Comment: for the latest version of nltk you need to use `nltk.downloader` instead of `nltk.download`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work ? Supposing your Anaconda env is called `myenv`.

```
source activate myenv
sudo python -c "import nltk; nltk.download()"
```

That's assuming having activated your env before would prevent using the base Linux's Python as you pointed out.