# IndexError found but can't find the problem

Tags: python, nltk

I was try this code

```
import OS
import nltk
print(os.listdir(nltk.data.find("corpora")))
```

but following error showed up.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-2-9f8c46ee9865> in <module>()
----> 1 print(os.listdir(nltk.data.find("corpora")))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in 
find(resource_name, paths)
    676 
    677     # Identify the package (i.e. the .zip file) to download.
--> 678     resource_zipname = resource_name.split('/')[1]
    679     if resource_zipname.endswith('.zip'):
    680         resource_zipname = resource_zipname.rpartition('.')[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: My guess is that `resource_name.split('/')` returns a list of a single element, and you're trying to access element 2 (index 1). The `resource_name` probably doesn't have the `'/'` character.

Comment: The library seems to expect something with a `/` as the argument.

Comment: The argument to `nltk.data.find()` is supposed to be a pathname to the file containing the corpus, not just a filename.

Comment: See the examples [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/data.html)

Comment: I have watched a tutorial and the instructor was getting the list of files in the corpora with the exact same line of code

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

You have to first download the `corpora`.

```
>>> import os
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular')
>>> print(os.listdir(nltk.data.find("corpora")))
```

But the printing of what's inside the `corpora` directory don't help much, maybe hints from this would be more helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30822962/610569

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'from **future** import print_function' to your code, so use the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import nltk
import nltk.corpus
nltk.download('popular')
print(os.listdir(nltk.data.find("corpora")))
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to Download the Data first.

See: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Import `nltk` library and downlowd the dataset you need:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

To test that the data has been installed:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
print(", ".join(brown.words()))
```

> The, Fulton, County, Grand, Jury, said, ...

Here assumes you downloaded the Brown Corpus.
See a list of the available corpus here: https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/

Comment: use nltk.download('all')