# downloading error using nltk.download()

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, nltk, spyder

I am experimenting NLTK package using Python. I tried to downloaded NLTK using `nltk.download()`. I got this kind of error message. How to solve this problem? Thanks.

The system I used is Ubuntu installed under VMware. The IDE is Spyder.

[image]

After using `nltk.download('all')`, it can download some packages, but it gets error message when downloading `oanc_masc`

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you installing [**python-nltk**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-nltk) using **apt-get**?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu you can install `nltk` however you want, but you then use `nltk.download()` to download the corpus data *after* you've installed it.

Comment: @Ffisegydd, do you have any solution to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you modified any of the settings at all?

Comment: I did not modify any setting. Just install ubuntu under vmware. The host system is windows 7.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with their server. Can't download nltk data as well. The server doesn't answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To download a particular dataset/models, use the `nltk.download()` function, e.g. if you are looking to download the `punkt` sentence tokenizer, use:

```
$ python3
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

If you're unsure of which data/model you need, you can start out with the basic list of data + models with:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular')
```

It will download a list of "popular" resources.

Ensure that you've the latest version of `NLTK` because it's always improving and constantly maintain:

```
$ pip install --upgrade nltk
```

---

## EDITED

In case anyone is avoiding errors from downloading larger datasets from `nltk`, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135306/610569

```
$ rm /Users/<your_username>/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_lite.zip
$ rm -r /Users/<your_username>/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_lite
$ python

>>> import nltk
>>> dler = nltk.downloader.Downloader()
>>> dler._update_index()
>>> dler._status_cache['panlex_lite'] = 'installed' # Trick the index to treat panlex_lite as it's already installed.
>>> dler.download('popular')
```

And if anyone wants to find `nltk_data` directory, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36383314/610569

And to config `nltk_data` path, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987374/610569

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried nltk.download('all'), it successfully proceeded with downloading some packages, but it got stuck when downloading sth related to oasc_masc, I included the related screenshot in the original post.

Comment: what is your nltk version? what is the output of this on your terminal: `python -c "import nltk; print nltk.__version__"`?

Comment: Hi there @alvas I'm having similar issues using nltk.download('all') on Ubuntu, except I get HTTP Error 404: Not Found in both IDLE and command line. My NLTK version is 2.0b9. Do you have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: @Joansy, Please update your NLTK. `sudo pip install nltk` or `sudo apt-get install python-nltk`. Once it's updated the problem should resolve itself. Otherwise, you would have to set the url manually. Try updating NLTK first, if it doesn't work, then come back again =)

Answer (score 8):

From command line, after importing nltk, try

```
nltk.download('popular', halt_on_error=False)
```

After an error it will ask to retry broken package, just decline with n and it will continue with proper packages.

Comment: I had several `UnicodeDecodeError`, and I had to launch this command several times in order to download everything, but it worked in the end. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

a) in OSX either run

`sudo /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command`

b) switch to admin user (the one you have set up with administrator privileges)

and type at command line:

`/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command`

**Notes:**

- "\" are necessary because they escape blank characters in file names.
- This procedure worked if you have python 3.6 installed, otherwise
  change it in order to match your install python version... for this
  execute:

`ls /Applications`

and look at the python directory name you have there.

Answer (score 1):

An easy(hard) way to get over this error is to do the process manually. Just go to the website `https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/` and download the required zip file and extract the contents.

In Windows, go to `user/AppData/local/Programs/Python/Python(version)/lib` and create a folder nltk_data. Then create the respective folder. As an example, for 'punkt' create the folder `tokenizers` and add the folder 'punkt' inside the extracted folder to it. This info is mostly given by the terminal itself.

Run your program. Cheers!

**EDIT 1**: Of course, downloading all files can be time-consuming, but it's the only option if the "urlopen error" persists.

**EDIT 2** It is also mostly your router or network at fault that you are not able to download nltk files. Try changing your network and that should help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a VPN it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First download it manually from `https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/` using an id and use a vpn for download and save it in, as shown path in error and then append `/nltk_data/corpora` folder and save your downloaded file in unzip format, then turn off VPN and again run same code, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install the data via commandline in my Ubuntu machine:

```
nlp$ python -m nltk.downloader all
/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py:126: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
[nltk_data] Error loading all: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection
[nltk_data]     reset by peer>
Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]
```

Then tried [manual installation](https://www.nltk.org/data.html#manual-installation):

1. mkdir  /usr/local/share/nltk_data
2. cd /usr/local/share/nltk_data
3. mkdir tokenizers # Other folders: chunkers, grammars, misc, sentiment, taggers, corpora, help, models, stemmers
4. cd tokenizers # I want to download a tokenizer
5. wget [http://URL/punkt.zip] # go to [NLTK Corpora](https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) and get the data URL you want.
6. unzip punkt.zip
7. # rm punkt.zip

I got an error *Unable to establish SSL connection* with *https*, so I went with *http*.

Answer (score 0):

Download link for NLTK is broken and throws a connection error

Download the files manually using the following steps

````
unzip gh-pages.zip
mkdir ~/nltk_data
mv nltk_data-gh-pages/nltk_data-gh-pages/packages/* nltk_data/
cd nltk_data/tokenizers/
unzip punkt.zip```
````

Answer (score -3):

I had this error:

```
Resource punkt not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource: import nltk nltk.download('punkt')
```

When I tried to solve by writing:

```
import nltk

nltk.download()
```

my computer shut downs suddenly and anaconda also closed. When I try to open it always shows an error.

I solved the problem by writing:

```
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')
```

Comment: This probably won't help. His problem was unable to nltk.download('all'), more likely only unable to nltk.download('oanc_masc')