# NLTK cannot find the file

Tags: php, python, nlp, nltk

I am having problems with a php script that says that it cannot find file /root/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle . However I confirmed that the file is here. II downloaded the whole data set multiple times)

The php script actually runs a python script and the nltk (a python module) says that it cannot find /root/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$command =  "/usr/bin/python ". $dir . "/test.py";
exec($command, $output);
```

On the other hands when i run the python script from command line it works perfectly fine and is able to access the file.

```
python test.py
```

Is it possible to enable php to see those files? I chmod 777 the file but this didn't help.

the script contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/ python
import  nltk
try:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize("I like apples.")
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    print "OK!"
    #print ' * '.join(tokens)
except Exception:
    print "error!"
    pass
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/my_domain_com/test.py", line 39, in <module>
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line   99, in pos_tag
tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg/nltk/data.py", line 605, in load
resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg/nltk/data.py", line 686, in _open
return find(path).open()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg/nltk/data.py", line 467, in find
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
Resource taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
>>> nltk.download()
Searched in:
- '/root/nltk_data'
- '/usr/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
```

---

Comment: Please post the full traceback error message. Is the php script being run as a different user than when you run it from the command line?

Comment: Echo the `$command` variable and check that it is correct.

Comment: yes the $command is correct, it works for other python modules except nltk

Comment: A have added the error log

Comment: I am pretty sure the user running php ius different than usee running from command line but I do not know how to check it.

Comment: I've tried your code on my PHP local machine server and it correctly runs the python with nltk libraries.

Comment: I am runing it on a centos vps, php 5.3.3. What do you use?

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons for the `Resource ... not found` error:

1. Paths to `nltk_data` not set correctly or `nltk_data` is not downloaded
2. `nltk_data` directory is outdated.

**Solution:**

Your problem is because your reason 2. So the simplest way is to delete all contents in your `nltk_data` directory and redownload all the contents using `python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('all')"`.

Also you're using an outdated `nltk` code so I suggest that you update to NLTK version 3.x since there are major changes from NLTK 2.x to NLTK 3.x

**Problem:**

The data structure of your `nltk_data` directory is as such:

```
nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle
```

but the latest `nltk_data` is:

```
nltk_data/taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle
```

This suggests that your nltk_data is not updated, although you're using a later version of the NLTK code.

---

**For reason 1, see below**

You do not have the `nltk_data` directory on these paths:

```
- '/root/nltk_data'
- '/usr/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
```

To assure that you have the postagger:

```
$ python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')
[nltk_data] Downloading package maxent_treebank_pos_tagger to
[nltk_data]     /home/alvas/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package maxent_treebank_pos_tagger is already up-to-
[nltk_data]       date!
True
```

Now you will see where nltk saves your data, for me, it's `/home/alvas/nltk_data`

To know which paths nltk searches for the directory:

```
$ python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.data.path
['/home/alvas/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']
```

You can also manually find where `nltk_data` directory is saved on your system and add it to the `nltk.data.path`, e.g. if nltk_data is saved in `/home/alvas/work_stuff/`:

```
>>> nltk.data.path.append(`/home/alvas/work_stuff/`)
```

To ensure that you have central installation, do:

```
sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all
```

Also see [downloading error using nltk.download()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658409/downloading-error-using-nltk-download/27660379#27660379)

Comment: doesn't make any difference

Comment: what is your nltk version?

Comment: I use 2.0.4 because it seems that 3.0 doesn't work with python 2.7.3

Comment: nltk supports from py2.6-py2.7. If you've found any part of the nltk that doesn't support py2.7.3, could you help to raise an issue in the github and the devs will resolve it asap.

Comment: have you tried deleting the `nltk_data` directory and redownloading it?

Comment: Will try something like that. Maybe load mnaually the file.

Comment: I hope it would. I redo the server installation so I now use python installed different way but the problem is still there. I would use 3.0 version but it doesn't work at all, not even word parser.

Comment: sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all this solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code on my PHP local machine server and it correctly runs the python with NLTK libraries.

My best guess is:

1. Check which user is running PHP by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771586/how-to-check-what-user-php-is-running-as).  Running:

   `echo exec('whoami');`

works for me on a linux environment.  Typically the user running php is `apache` if you are using Apache web server.

2. Check that the user running PHP has read permissions to the `/root/nltk_data` folder (or whichever folder you placed the NLTK data in).

Comment: 1) user is apache, i have just checked.

Comment: Actually i do not now how to check 2, because i can only do "ls -l" command inside root folder. I made nltk_data folder 777.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Who knows why :)

Comment: Just noticed you only made the folder 777. You should make the folder and all contents in it 777.  Do a chmod -R 777 on the directory.