# unable to completely download nltk package in python. stops at omw

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, python-3.5

I am unable to complete the nltk package download. It always stops at the items omw (Open Multilingual Wordnet). These are the only two remaining ones. I have looked at other help items (i.e. [install ntlk supporting packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750608/error-installing-nltk-supporting-packages-nltk-download) or [error installing Nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658409/downloading-error-using-nltk-download)) but the problem persists. It returns the error code 11001, i.e. wrong server location. But the server index http://ntlk.org/nltk_data/ worked for all other items. I am a bit lost here.

Print scree of error message can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chIMl.png)

I use python 3.5 and have the latest nltk file (downloaded and unzipped it last night)

Many thanks!

Comment: did Luis' answer work for you?

Comment: @alvas it worked partly. Thanks asking. I have decided to uninstall everything and go 32 bit as it seems that nltk and numpy don't work well on the 64 bit Python version.

Comment: it's a 64 bit issue, things are crazy on windows.

Comment: thanks for confirming - working my way through. eventually I'll make it work ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you connecting to the internet with a proxy server? If so, try this:

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
nltk.download()
```

Alternatively, try this:

Open a terminal window (Use the “Run...” option on the Start menu). Go to the directory where Python is installed, for example C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\

type:

```
python -m nltk.downloader all
```

If all that fails, you should try downloading the data manually from here: http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ and then put your data in the C:\nltk_data directory.

Comment: Thanks! The second option "python -m nltk.downloader.all" seemed to work in the sense that I didn't get an error message. I don't use a proxy, but Win 8.1 64 bit.

However, when I try a simple example it doesn't work. 
The example I tried:

text = 'hello world! I wish I had more sleep.'

print (word_tokenize(text)) 


The error message says it doesn't find the function "word_tokenize". I have not yet successfully installed numpy and matplotlib. Do I need numpy or another package for ntlk to work?

Comment: @Simone, I think you are dealing with multiple issues. If the download part worked (no errors) as per my answer, I suggest you accept it so it is marked as closed, and ask another question about the second issue. Thanks.

Comment: yes import nltk worked fine. Decided to uninstall everything and start afresh with the 32 bit version. As per your suggestion I closed this item.

Comment: Thank you Simone. Good luck!