# Error message with nltk.sentiment.vader in Python

Tags: python, nltk

I am a beginner at Python and am trying to use nltk.sentiment.vader but get a recurrent error message despite multiple attempts to fix it.  I previously installed most of NTLK (3 modules were out of date so couldn't install them).  I then installed nltk.sentiment.vader using the command line prompt and my output was "Successfully installed vaderSentiment-2.5".   "vaderSentiment in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages". I then run the script below and repeatedly get the error message below:

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence_that_I want_to_analyze)  
print(ss)
```

output:

LookupError:

---

Resource
  'sentiment/vader_lexicon.zip/vader_lexicon/vader_lexicon.txt'
  not found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the
  resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\Users\name/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Anaconda\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Anaconda\lib\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data'
    - ''

---

I noticed that the error message doesn't include the location where the package was installed =c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages.  Is this the reason that I am getting this error?  How do I fix this?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: the error is stated : you don't have the source data it needs. Are you sure you have it? Did you download sources after you installed NLTK? It has its own GUI installer to download these sources and it seems that it can't find the files where they should be

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I am not sure what you mean by did I download sources after I downloaded NTLK ? I downloaded ntlk by nltk.download() then I selected all.  After this I installed vader as above.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: regardless of NLTK and python, do you have vader_lexicon.txt on your computer? If not you should go again through the download step and make sure to download the package without error. I'm not sure what's happening but the error is pretty clear : you just don't have the file (at the right location?)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I re downloaded nltk it using the code from this post and it now works:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658409/downloading-error-using-nltk-download

Answer (score 22):

```
import nltk
nltk.downloader.download('vader_lexicon')
```

instead of 'vader_lexicon',put your desired package

Answer (score 8):

You have to install it from NLTK's installer. If you're like me, you figured it out, but you still don't know the package's name.

Follow these steps:

`python` > `import nltk` > `nltk.download()` > `d` > `vader_lexicon`

That should do it. If `d` isn't recognized try `Download`.

[image]

Comment: nltk.download() seems to open a GUI now but the dataset still has the same name!

Comment: @GarethD Doesn't happen to me even though I have the latest version installed (I tried both with python 2.7 and 3.6).