# how to fix it up about the certificate verify failed when download the Punkt from nltk package python?

Tags: python-3.x

When I was trying to using the nltk downloader in pycharm it seems that not working. Then, I tried to download manually while it shows the links is not private as: "Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from raw.githubusercontent.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID?
Does anyone could help me with it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEee0.png)

I have tried many methods like but did not figure it out:

[SSL error downloading NLTK data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348621/ssl-error-downloading-nltk-data)
the certifi is updated while the nlkt downloader is still not working.

https://github.com/

[downloading error using nltk.download()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658409/downloading-error-using-nltk-download)

I used mccOS,  version 11.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Clearing my local host could solve the problem in my case.