# can't use punkt tokenizer with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, nlp, nltk, pyspark

I am trying to use the punkt tokenizer from the NLTK package with pyspark on a Spark standalone cluster.  NLTK has been installed on the individual nodes, but the nltk_data folder doesn't reside where NLTK expects it (/usr/share/nltk_data).

I am attempting to use the punkt tokenizer, which is located in (whatever/my_user/nltk_data).

I have set:

```
envv1   = "/whatever/my_user/nltk_data"
os.environ['NLTK_DATA'] = envv1
```

Printing nltk.data.path indicates that the first entry is where my nltk_data folder is actually located.

The `from nltk import word_tokenize` goes fine, but when it comes to calling the function `word_tokenize()` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named nltk.tokenize
```

For whatever reason, I have no trouble accessing resources from nltk.corpus.  When I try nltk.download(), it is clear I already have the punkt tokenizer downloaded.  I can even use the punkt tokenizer outside of pyspark.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to config nltk data directory from code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522372/how-to-config-nltk-data-directory-from-code)

Comment: Use `nltk.data.path.append("/home/yourusername/whateverpath/")`

Comment: I actually can't get the nltk.data.path.append() to work. It looks like it only sets it on the master and all the others nodes dont know where to look.

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work?

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to send the nltk_data directory to all nodes using, for example, `sc.addFile()`