# Install nltk data in airgapped environment

Tags: python, hadoop, nltk, anaconda

I want to leverage NLTK for NLP tasks on a hadoop cluster through Pyspark. We use an Anaconda distribution.
The cluster is in an air-gapped environment, thus I cannot run `nltk.download()`.

I'm thinking I need to download the data on a secondary machine with internet access. Where do I download it from? And how do I install it on the hadoop cluster? Do I just copy the files? Or does nltk needs to know where the data is? Does the data need to be copied on all nodes?

Comment: "Does the data need to be copied on all nodes?" Yes but what are you using the data for? Which dataset do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I download it from?

You could execute `nltk.download()` on your machine and the data would get downloaded into your home directory under folder `nltk_data`

> And how do I install it on the hadoop cluster? Do I just copy the files? Or does nltk needs to know where the data is?

It should be sufficient if you copy the `nltk_data` to the home folder on the machines under the user that executes the processes. If it is not possible, you can use  `NLTK_DATA` environment variable to set the location. See [How to config nltk data directory from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522372/how-to-config-nltk-data-directory-from-code) for more discussion about this

> Does the data need to be copied on all nodes?

Yes