# Change nltk.download() path directory from default ~/ntlk_data

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, nltk, default

I was trying to download/update python `nltk` packages on a computing server and it returned this `[Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded:` error.

Specifically:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stop words to /home/sh2264/nltk_data...
[nltk_data] Error downloading u'stopwords' from
[nltk_data] <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-
[nltk_data] pages/packages/corpora/stopwords.zip>: [Errno 122]
[nltk_data] Disk quota exceeded:
[nltk_data] u'/home/sh2264/nltk_data/corpora/stopwords.zip
False
```

How could I change the entire path for `nltk` packages, and what other changes should I make to ensure errorless loading of `nltk`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can be configured both by command-line (`nltk.download(..., download_dir=)` or by GUI. Bizarrely nltk seems to totally ignore its own environment variable `NLTK_DATA` and default its download directories to a standard set of five paths, regardless whether `NLTK_DATA` is defined and where it points, and regardless whether nltk's five default dirs even exist on the machine or architecture(!). Some of that is documented in [Installing NLTK Data](http://www.nltk.org/data.html), although it's incomplete and kinda buried; reproduced below with much clearer formatting:

> ### Command line installation
>
> The downloader will search for an existing `nltk_data` directory to
>   install NLTK data. If one does not exist it will attempt to create one
>   in a central location (when using an administrator account) or
>   otherwise in the user’s filespace. If necessary, run the download
>   command from an administrator account, or using sudo. The recommended
>   system location is:
>
> - `C:\nltk_data` (Windows) ;
> - `/usr/local/share/nltk_data` (Mac) and
> - `/usr/share/nltk_data` (Unix).
>
> You can use the -d flag to specify a different location (but if you do this, be sure to set the NLTK_DATA environment variable accordingly).
>
> - Run the command `python -m nltk.downloader all`
> - To ensure central installation, run the command: `sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data all`
> - But really they should say: `sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d $NLTK_DATA all`

Now as to **what recommended path NLTK_DATA should use**, nltk doesn't really give any proper guidance, but it should be a generic standalone path not under any install tree (so not under `<python-install-directory>/lib/site-packages`) or any user dir. Hence, `/usr/local/share`, `/opt/share` or similar. On MacOS 10.7+, `/usr` and thus `/usr/local/` these days are hidden by default, so `/opt/share` may well be a better choice. Or do `chflags nohidden /usr/local/share`.

Comment: This is not the behavior I see.. as root in a docker container it downloads into /root/nltk_data.

Comment: @user239558: which OS and nltk version?

Comment: If we download only stopwords for the specific directory in Linux `sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data stopwords`

Comment: @HansikaHettiarachchi you can specify more than one download. `sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data stopwords wordnet punkt`

Comment: @user239558 et al, if you found a docbug, please [report it to nltk](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: you need to specify the path including the `nltk_data` part, so if you want to install in `/usr/share` then the command (within the Python shell) is `nltk.download('...',download_dir='/usr/share/nltk_data')`.

Answer (score 28):

According to the [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#download-directory):

> By default, packages are installed in either a system-wide directory (if Python has sufficient access to write to it); or in the current user’s home directory. However, the download_dir argument may be used to specify a different installation target, if desired.

To specify the download directory, use for example:

```
nltk.download('treebank', download_dir='/mnt/data/treebank')
```

Comment: To retrieve some nltk's downloaded packages you may need to also include the `download_dir` to nltk's data path -> `nltk.data.path.append('/mnt/data/treebank')`

Answer (score 3):

You may also use `nltk.download_shell()` and follow the interactive steps as shown below.

[image]

Also use `nltk.data.path.append('/your/new/data/directory/path')` to instruct nltk to to load data from new data path.

Answer (score 0):

[image: NLTK Download GUI Screeshot (Windows)]

NLTK GUI can be started from PyCharm Community Edition Python console too. 
Just issue 2 commands:

**1) import nltk**

**2) nltk.download_gui()**

but nltk GUI will not work if you are behind a proxy server for that at the console you must first set proxy setting

**SET HTTP_PROXY=proxy.mycompany.com:8080**

and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the solution purely from shell commands (no python code).

First use this command line to download to a custom directory:

```
python -m nltk.downloader -d /my/path/nltk_data all
```

And then at runtime for nltk to find the custom directory, set the environment variable:

```
export NLTK_DATA=/my/path/nltk_data
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

If the environment variable `NLTK_DATA` is set *and* the directory exists, it is used as default download directory.

## Explanation

In the [data](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py) module the environment variable `NLTK_DATA` is used as [first entry](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/3.7/nltk/data.py#L71) when filling the data search path.

If `download_dir` is not specified as parameter when calling [nltk.download()](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/3.7/nltk/downloader.py#L743) the method [default_download_dir()](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/3.7/nltk/downloader.py#L1049) determines the download directory.

## Example: Create new default data directory

One would like to use `/usr/local/share/nltk_data` as default data directory.

Create the data directory and add `NLTK_DATA` to your shell profile.

```
$ mkdir /usr/local/share/nltk_data
$ echo "export NLTK_DATA=/usr/local/share/nltk_data" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ echo $NLTK_DATA
/usr/local/share/nltk_data
```

Now `nltk` uses `/usr/local/share/nltk_data` as defined in `NLTK_DATA`.

```
$ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Sep  5 2022, 11:08:58) [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('gutenberg')
[nltk_data] Downloading package gutenberg to
[nltk_data]     /usr/local/share/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/gutenberg.zip.
True
```

## Example: Switch default data directory

The current data directory is `~/nltk_data` and one would like to use the directory `/usr/local/share/nltk_data` instead.

Move the data directory and add `NLTK_DATA` to your shell profile.

```
$ mv ~/nltk_data /usr/local/share/nltk_data
$ echo "export NLTK_DATA=/usr/local/share/nltk_data" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ echo $NLTK_DATA
/usr/local/share/nltk_data
```

Now `nltk` uses `/usr/local/share/nltk_data` as defined in `NLTK_DATA`.

```
$ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Sep  5 2022, 11:08:58) [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('gutenberg')
[nltk_data] Downloading package gutenberg to
[nltk_data]     /usr/local/share/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package gutenberg is already up-to-date!
True
```

Answer (score 0):

[smci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202229/smci) said:

> nltk seems to totally ignore its own environment variable NLTK_DATA

Actually,

- nltk ignores NLTK_DATA for nltk.download(...)
- nltk ignores NLTK_DATA defined **after** 'import nltk'

so :

```
import  nltk
os.environ["NLTK_DATA"]="/some/path"
// use nltk and expect it to use "/some/path"
```

woulds not work, whereas :

```
os.environ["NLTK_DATA"]="/some/path"
import  nltk
// use nltk and expect it to use "/some/path"
```

would work.

Furthermore, for nltk.download, you can define your selected download_dir

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here but I needed to control where data was downloaded, without explicitly sending it to the download function. Looking into the code I found that if `download_dir` is not send, it uses the default attribute in the `nltk.downloader.Downloader` class, which his is instantiated when you import nltk so you can update it after that by using:

```
nltk.downloader._downloader.download_dir = download_dir
```