# Install nltk on Docker

Tags: python, docker, nltk, dockerfile

I am new to docker, and I am trying to install some packages of nltk on docker
Here is my docker file

```
FROM python:3-onbuild

RUN python -m libs.py

COPY start.sh /libs.py

COPY start.sh /start.sh

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

Here is My libs.py which contain the packages of nltk to download

```
import nltk
nltk.data.path.append('./')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('pros_cons')
nltk.download('snowball_data')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru')
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('universal_tagset')
nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')
nltk.download('hmm_treebank_pos_tagger')
nltk.download('reuters')
nltk.download('treebank')
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
nltk.download('porter_test')
nltk.download('rslp')
```

Docker Image created successfully but when I try to use these packages it throwing me error

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')

  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

Can anybody tell why the nltk packages not installed? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to create a user inside Docker. You should try to avoid being root in Docker (by default).

Nevertheless you can set the [`download_dir` when using `nltk.download()`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/downloader.py#L652):

> download(self, 
>            info_or_id=None, 
>            **download_dir=None**, 
>            quiet=False,
>            force=False, 
>            prefix='[nltk_data] ', 
>            halt_on_error=True,
>            raise_on_error=False):

And if no value is set for `download_dir`, [it will try to save it the default path](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/downloader.py#L441):

```
    # decide where we're going to save things to.
    if self._download_dir is None:
        self._download_dir = self.default_download_dir()
```

More specifically: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/downloader.py#L919

```
def default_download_dir(self):
    """
    Return the directory to which packages will be downloaded by
    default.  This value can be overridden using the constructor,
    or on a case-by-case basis using the ``download_dir`` argument when
    calling ``download()``.
    On Windows, the default download directory is
    ``PYTHONHOME/lib/nltk``, where *PYTHONHOME* is the
    directory containing Python, e.g. ``C:\\Python25``.
    On all other platforms, the default directory is the first of
    the following which exists or which can be created with write
    permission: ``/usr/share/nltk_data``, ``/usr/local/share/nltk_data``,
    ``/usr/lib/nltk_data``, ``/usr/local/lib/nltk_data``, ``~/nltk_data``.
    """
```

Thus it's saving the file at `/root/nltk_data/`

It looks like you're accessing `/` directory when you run `CMD ["/start.sh"]` the docker image, so perhaps you have some permission settings with `/root/nltk_data`.

## In short

Explicitly set the path where you want the `nltk_data` directory to be downloaded:

```
nltk.download('popular', download_dir='/path/to/nltk_data/')
```

When running a new python instance,

```
nltk.data.path.append('/path/to/nltk_data/')
```

See also: 
[How to config nltk data directory from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522372/how-to-config-nltk-data-directory-from-code)

Comment: I add the download_dir='./libs_data/nltk_data/' but it giving me this error while unzipping the package files                                                             `The command '/bin/sh -c python -m libs.py' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: Docker doesn't like dynamic paths, give a static path. Also, it's advisable to  create a user in docker, not use root.

Comment: by adding `nltk.data.path.append('/path/to/nltk')` into settings.py of django app it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `nltk.data.path.append('/path/to/nltk_data')` in your `settings.py` file and the the procedure is same

`libs.py` contain all the packges detail

After that add this into your docker file

```
RUN pip install nltk

RUN python nltk_pkg.py

COPY start.sh /nltk_pkg.py

COPY start.sh /start.sh
```

It works for me.