# How to include nltk data while building my python project?

Tags: python, nltk

I have developed a python project and i have researched on packaging these kind of projects along with their dependencies.
However, my problem is that i am functioning under a proxy which does not allow downloading nltk data through nltk.download()
So i had to manually download and place the data in nltk_data folder
Now that my project has developed I want to distribute this across multiple systems and dont want the users to manually download and arrange the nltk data directory.
Any help in packaging this data for offline usage is appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522372/how-to-config-nltk-data-directory-from-code ?

Comment: @alvas i dont think so.
I am basically looking to build a single installable which will automatically place the required data in the necessary directory.
I want to package this along with the installable and not send that as a separate dependency for the user to configure.