# nltk download not working inside docker for a django service

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, nltk

I am trying to launch a django service using docker which uses nltk library. 
In the dockerfile I have called a setup.py which calls nltk.download. According to the logs I see during building the docker image this step runs successfully.

But when I run the docker image and try to connect to my django service, I get the error saying that nltk.download hasn't happened yet.

Dockerfile code -

```
RUN . ${PYTHON_VIRTUAL_ENV_FOLDER}/bin/activate && python ${PYTHON_APP_FOLDER}/setup.py
```

setup.py code -

```
import nltk
import os

nltk.download('stopwords', download_dir=os.getcwd() + '/nltk_data/')
nltk.download('wordnet', download_dir=os.getcwd() + '/nltk_data/')
```

Error:

```
**********************************************************************
  Resource stopwords not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('stopwords')

  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/src/venv/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/src/venv/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/src/venv/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

Any idea what is wrong here? 
Also, the same code works when I run it without docker.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  Can you add the actual error message, the Dockerfile, and your `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` to the question?

Comment: `docker run -it -e ENVIRONMENT_NAME=local -e REGION_NAME=local -p 9081:8080 docker_image` - The run command

Comment: @DavidMaze - I have already added the relevant line from Dockerfile in the question. Also, added the error message and docker-run command.

Comment: Mount the `nltk_data`, `docker build -f Dockerfile -v $HOME/nltk_data/:/nltk_data/`. Then before `setup.py`, in Dockerfile, `ENV NLTK_DATA=/nltk_data/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having faced that same problem before and having done *almost* the same thing you did, I'd assume what you're missing here is configuring the [`nltk.data.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522372/how-to-config-nltk-data-directory-from-code) by adding to the path wherever your `os.getcwd()` is.

Comment: This worked thanks! but with a slight tweak. I had to specify this env variable in Dockerfile and then also use an add statement. 
`ENV NLTK_DATA /app/nltk_data/`
`ADD . $NLTK_DATA`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post and it fixed my issue as well!!!!

I got the same issue that punkt does exit in docker:

```
/root/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt
```

But when my app tried to reach it, Docker kept complaining the resource couldn't be found.

Inspired by your post, I added:

```
ENV NLTK_DATA /root/nltk_data/
ADD . $NLTK_DATA
```

But still got the same error message. So I tried this:

```
ENV NLTK_DATA /nltk_data/
ADD . $NLTK_DATA
```

I didn't know why I wanted to remove /root from the path but it worked!

My app is using Flask and uWSGI, so I guess maybe this is an issue for Django and Flask? Thanks anyway!