# Configure New NLTK Path

Tags: python, append, nltk

I am working with nltk in python. I imported the package and downloaded the additional data just fine, but I want to be able to append a new directory to store nltk_data.

When I tried this fix found at this link ([How to config nltk data directory from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522372/how-to-config-nltk-data-directory-from-code))

```
nltk.data.path.append("path")
```

I received this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can try checking what nltk.data.path stores.
most probably you assigned the path as string (may be in a notebook session)
nltk.data.path.append = "folder path" (this is incorrect way)

you should first clear your session or restart your session if you made above change.