# How can I download NLTK corpora via `requirements.txt` using `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Tags: python, pip, nltk, corpus, requirements.txt

One can download NLTK corpora `punkt` and `wordnet` via the command line:

```
python3 -m nltk.downloader punkt wordnet
```

How can I download NLTK corpora via `requirements.txt` using `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

For example one can download spacy models `requirements.txt` using `pip install -r requirements.txt` by adding the URL of the model  (e.g. https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.0.0
in `requirements.txt`)

Comment: Wordnet can be isolated with the stand-alone https://github.com/nltk/wordnet

Comment: @alvas thanks, good to know!

Answer (score 5):

> How can I download NLTK corpora via `requirements.txt`

Short answer: no way.

The URL for spacy models points to a **Python package** (`setup.py` and all that) so it can be downloaded and installed by `pip`. There are no such `pip`-installable packages for NLTK data. `nltk.downloader` downloads data in its own format.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to actually do this via a requirements.txt file. However, if it is necessary for you to use NLTK for wordnet and punkt what you can do is have 2 files. And download the nltk data in one and import that file into your main file. For example,

nltkmodules.py:

```py
import nltk

nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('punkt')
```

main.py:

```py
import nltkmodules

# Rest of Code goes here
```

In your requirements.txt, you can just include:

```
nltk==3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Download using commandline:

```
python -m nltk.downloader stopwords punkt wordnet
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I download NLTK corpora **via** `requirements.txt` using `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: There's no straight forward way as requirement.txt expects python package names hosted on pypi repositories, or a local package. You could however create a `requirements_nltk.txt` and create a custom python package (local or hosted), that contains the actual files of nltk package. Then run `pip install --download=/user/home/nltk/ -r requirements_nltk.txt` and while using the package, use, configure the `nltk data dir` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522372/how-to-config-nltk-data-directory-from-code) Super hacky i know